# Using :includes with variables and further queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here's a query:

```
@projects = @user.projects.includes(:company => :workers)
```

In my view, I want to order a list of these projects by the [tags](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) that belong to the company.

So, projects belonging to the company's `urgent` tag come first, then `elevated`, then all others.

I think one way to do this is to define `@companies`, then define:

```
@urgent = @companies.tagged_with('urgent')
@elevated = @companies.tagged_with('elevated')
@others = @companies.tagged_with('urgent', 'elevated', :exclude => true)

# view:
@urgent.each do |u| ... end
@elevated.each do |e| ... end
@others.each do |o| ... end
```

#### 1. How do I get @companies in the first place?

How can you collect all the companies together when the first query is the one I showed at the top? `@companies = @projects.collect{|p| p.company}` produces a non-searchable array.

#### 2. Is there a more elegant way of displaying the projects than doing three loops?

Comment: Depending on the Model relationship between Projects and Companies , you could try `@companies = @projects.companies`. You could also "dump" the @projects object in your view using `<%= debug @projects%>` and inspect the object to get to @companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do this without using 2 queries.

```
@projects = @user.projects.includes(:company => :workers)
@companies = Company.find(@projects.collect(&:id))
```

As for rendering the tags, you could do:

```
ordered_tags = ['urgent', 'elevated']

ordered_tags.each do |tag|
  @companies.tagged_with(tag).each do |company|
    my_render_logic
  end
end

@companies.tagged_with(*ordered_tags, :exclude => true).each do |company|
  my_render_logic
end
```

Comment: What does the asterisk mean in `*ordered_tags`?

Comment: I dont know if tagged_with accepts a list. If it does, then you dont need to add the asterisk. In case it doesnt, it would convert the list into arguments.

Comment: i.e., it would be equivalent to calling `@companies.tagged_with('urgent', 'elevated', :exclude => true)`